# segmenting parent div height to use for child divs

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a div with an specific height. i want this: i put some nested `div's` inside this div an tell them use specific percentage of height of the parent div. for example: `div1=10%, div2=50% and div3=40%`. Im talking about height.

Im using bootstrap and i can control location of parts of a row via `col-*`, But i want this for height of a parent div. How i can achieve this via Bootstrap?

```
<div id="parent" stele="height:500px;">
 <div class="child">text 1</div>
 <div class="child">text 2</div>
 <div class="child">text 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have of html code?

Comment: @VDesign: i updated my question. my parent has 500px height but im seeking for a universal way.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap grid system will make it easy for you to make responsive columns, because that is a cumbersome part to handle yourself for differing screen-sizes without horizontal scrolling. For height, you can rely on plain CSS styles, because vertical scrolling is not a problem.

Whatever your use-case be, just remember that percent dimensions are always relative to an element's parent. So if you want to give an element a height of *10%* you need to consider the question: *10% of what?*.

Following snippet will hopefully make it clear to you.

**Snippet**:

```css
.parent { height: 120px; border: 1px solid gray; }
.parent div:nth-child(1) { height: 20%; background-color: #f00; }
.parent div:nth-child(2) { height: 50%; background-color: #00f; }
.parent div:nth-child(3) { height: 30%; background-color: #0f0; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="parent col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
            <div class="child">text 1</div>
            <div class="child">text 2</div>
            <div class="child">text 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there any other way other than using percentage? like bootstrap's grid system for rows...

Comment: @Fcoder: You could devise your own system. Just name your classes accordingly. That is what Bootstrap does for cols. For example `col-xs-12` is 100% width and `col-xs-6` is 50%. All responsive sizes are in percents.